# Slight error when using awk to remove spaces from a CSV column

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have used the following awk command on my bash script to delete spaces on the 26th column of my CSV;

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {gsub(/ /,"",$26)}1' original.csv > final.csv
```

Out of 400 rows, I have about 5 random rows that this doesn't work on even if I rerun the script on final.csv. Can anyone assist me with a method to take care of this? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** Here is a sample of the 26th column on original.csv vs final.csv respectively;

```
2212026837                         2212026837
2256  41688  6                     2256416886
2076113566                         2076113566
2009  84517  7                     2009845177
2067950476                         2067950476
2057  90531  5                     2057  90531  5  
2085271676                         2085271676
2095183426                         2095183426
2347366235                         2347366235
2200160434                         2200160434
2229359595                         2229359595
2045373466                         2045373466
2053849895                         2053849895
2300  81552  3                     2300  81552  3
```

Comment: Guessing the rows aren't random and are somehow different from the others, just a guess though as you have provided practically no useful information.

Comment: Wild guess: Do the 26th fields in those rows contain tabs or other non-0x20 whitespace, or does one of the previous fields in those rows contain a quoted string with a comma in it?

Comment: Hi. I have updated my question with a sample of the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possibilities.

1. The simplest is that you have some whitespace other than a space. You can fix that by using a more general regex in your `gsub`: instead of `/ /`, use `/[[:space:]]/`.

If that solves your problem, great! You got lucky, move on. :)

2. The other possible problem is trickier.  The CSV (or, in this case, pipe-SV) format is not as simple as it appears, since you can have quoted delimiters inside fields. This, for instance, is a perfectly valid 4-field line in a pipe-delimited file:

   ```
   field 1|"field 2 contains some |pipe| characters"|field 3|field 4
   ```

   If the first 4 fields on a line in your file looked like that, your `gsub` on `$26` would actually operate on `$24` instead, leaving `$26` alone.  If you have data like that, the only real solution is to use a scripting language with an actual CSV parsing library.  Perl has `Text::CSV`, but it's not installed by default; Python's `csv` module is, so you could use a program like so:

   ```
   import csv, fileinput as fi, re;    
   for row in csv.reader(fi.input(), delimiter='|'):
     row[25] = re.sub(r'\s+', '', row[25]) # fields start at 0 instead of 1
     print '|'.join(row)
   ```

   Save the above in a file like `colfixer.py` and run it with `python colfixer.py original.csv >final.csv`.

   (If you tried hard enough, you could get that shoved into a `-c` option string and run it from the command line without creating a script file, but Python's not really built for that and it gets ugly fast.)

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. Turns out the first possibility is not it. I therefore tried the python script but it only records the last line. I am looking into it but if you know what the issue might be it sure would save me a lot of time :). Thank you once again.

Comment: Is the `print '|'.join(row)` line indented at the same level as the `row[25] =` line?  They should both be indented so that they're inside the `for` loop; if the `print` is outdented to match the `for`, then it will only print the last line.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution works. However, my CSV has issues with the delimiters on some row. I think there are some quotation marks bringing about the confusion. I will look into this. Once again, thank you very much  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [string function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) `split`, and iterate over the corresponding array to reassign the 26th field:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {
    n = split($26, a, /[[:space:]]+/)
    $26=a[1]
    for(i=2; i<=n; i++)
        $26=$26""a[i]
}1' original.csv > final.csv
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much but this gives me "illegal reference to array a" error.

Comment: Ah, yes, you must not be using GNU awk as using `length` on arrays is a GNU awk extension.  It makes more sense here to use the returned value from the `split` function as that will be the number of elements in the array.  See update for working version.

Comment: I realized that /[[:space:]]/ doesn't give me any results so I tried / / but even with this, the fields that don't change are still persistent.

Comment: @Mardwan My mistake, it should actually be `[[:space:]]+`.  But if for some reason your awk does not support use of POSIX character classes like `[[:space:]]`, you can substitute it with `[\t ]+`.

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck :(